# Wolfram Alpha: How to define constants in a system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computer-algebra-systems, wolfram-alpha

I'd like to use WA to solve a small system of nonlinear equations, that involve both constants and the variables of interest.  How do I "tell" WA which variables are the constants, and which are the ones I want it to solve for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Solve** [equations separated by commas] **for** [variables separated by commas]

In Wolfram Mathematica it's Solve[{eq1,eq2,...},{x1,x2,...}] so it should work in WA too.

Comment: It deserved to be an accepted one here. +1

Comment: This isn't working for a larger system I'm attempting to solve: `solve i(p-s)+j(p-n)=0, k(n)+l(n-o)=0, l(o-A(p-n))+mo=0 for p, n, A`

Comment: @sudo that's probably because k(n) seems like a function. You probably meant k*n. And also m*o instead of mo.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me

```
solve  a+b+x -y = 5 , b-x-y = 10 for x and y
```

or

```
solve  a+b+x-y = 5 , b-x-y +z= 10, x+z=0 for x ,y, z
```

See the results [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%20a%2bb%2bx%20-y%20=%205%20,%20b-x-y%20=%2010%20for%20x%20and%20y%20) or [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%20a%2bb%2bx-y%20=%205%20,%20b-x-y%20%2bz=%2010,%20x%2bz=0%20for%20x%20,y,%20z%20).

Comment: This is a question; sorry. How can i solve Diophantine equations over the integers with Wolfram alpha? For instance:solve  3x^2-y^2=2,8x^2-z^2=7 for x , y ,z over the integers.

Comment: extracted from the Wolfram Alpha this should work
`solve 3x+4y=5 , y+z=2 over the integers`
see 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+3x%2B4y%3D5+%2C+y%2Bz%3D2+over+the+integers